# Why can't I find hardware cache event in my perf list?

Tags: perf, perf-event

I have a problem in using linux perf on a newly bought laptop: there is no available hardware cache effect in my perf list!!! Well, this is really all important information that I wish to sample!! Here is my perf list:

```
List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):
cpu-cycles OR cycles                               [Hardware event]
instructions                                       [Hardware event]
cache-references                                   [Hardware event]
cache-misses                                       [Hardware event]
branch-instructions OR branches                    [Hardware event]
branch-misses                                      [Hardware event]
bus-cycles                                         [Hardware event]
ref-cycles                                         [Hardware event]

cpu-clock                                          [Software event]
task-clock                                         [Software event]
page-faults OR faults                              [Software event]
context-switches OR cs                             [Software event]
cpu-migrations OR migrations                       [Software event]
minor-faults                                       [Software event]
major-faults                                       [Software event]
alignment-faults                                   [Software event]
emulation-faults                                   [Software event]
dummy                                              [Software event]

branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
branch-misses OR cpu/branch-misses/                [Kernel PMU event]
bus-cycles OR cpu/bus-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/                  [Kernel PMU event]
cache-references OR cpu/cache-references/          [Kernel PMU event]
cpu-cycles OR cpu/cpu-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
instructions OR cpu/instructions/                  [Kernel PMU event]
power/energy-cores/                                [Kernel PMU event]
power/energy-gpu/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
power/energy-pkg/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
power/energy-ram/                                  [Kernel PMU event]
ref-cycles OR cpu/ref-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]

rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
(see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)

mem:<addr>[:access]                                [Hardware breakpoint]

[ Tracepoints not available: Permission denied ]
```

while this is the perf list I used to see: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Events.

What I used to do is:

```
sudo perf stat -e L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,LLC-loads,LLC-load-misses -a --append -o perf.txt [some command to run a file]
```

but this does not work on my new machine. How can I collect data I want in this case?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, with kernel <3.19.0-56>. Perf version <3.19.8-ckt15>.

---

**update**

I installed the `papi-tools` library, and `papi_native_avail` gives me

```
Available native events and hardware information.

PAPI Version             : 5.3.0.0
Vendor string and code   : GenuineIntel (1)
Model string and code    : Intel(R) Core(TM) M-5Y71 CPU @ 1.20GHz (61)
CPU Revision             : 4.000000
CPUID Info               : Family: 6  Model: 61  Stepping: 4
CPU Max Megahertz        : 2900
CPU Min Megahertz        : 500
Hdw Threads per core     : 1
Cores per Socket         : 2
Sockets                  : 2
NUMA Nodes               : 1
CPUs per Node            : 4
Total CPUs               : 4
Running in a VM          : no
Number Hardware Counters : 0
Max Multiplex Counters   : 64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if the processor has even the hardware counters. Intel Haswell architecture stopped to provide hardware counters in recent processors (for some reason).

Second of all, I would check if you can see hardware event through, for example `papi`. The command `papi_native_avail` should list you native events, if Ubuntu provides recent enough databases.

The third possibility is that the events are here, but not supported by the old `perf`. Yes, Ubuntu 14.04 is two years old and the kernel/tools might not support current processors fully.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my update. I have put on the output of `papi_native_avail`. I see that the number of hardware counters is 0.

Comment: Are the first point and the second the same thing?

Comment: Well, if Intel stops providing hardware event counter.... Ah, let me make a guess. Does intel want people to use his own tool: `Intel PCM` or `Intel VTune` instead?

Comment: Basically yes. But it is the easiest way to "verify" the first point :) I tried to search for some data-sheet, but I have no success on their pages. I don't know about `Intel PCM` nor `Intel VTune`, but if there are no hardware counters, there is no way to get any information about performance.

Comment: Well, that is really bad news... in the future there is no way to get cache statistics...

Answer (score 4):

Also worth noting is that `perf list` can give you different output depending on whether or not it's running as `root`.  (Perhaps there's some configuration setting that makes `root` not be the deciding factor; I'm not sure.)

On my Linux Mint 18.1 box, running a 4.8.0-34-generic kernel:

```
$ perf list cache

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

$ sudo perf list cache

List of pre-defined events (to be used in -e):

  L1-dcache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-loads                                    [Hardware cache event]
  L1-dcache-stores                                   [Hardware cache event]
  L1-icache-load-misses                              [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-load-misses                                    [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-loads                                          [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-store-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  LLC-stores                                         [Hardware cache event]
  branch-load-misses                                 [Hardware cache event]
  branch-loads                                       [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  iTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
  node-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
  node-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
  node-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
```

Comment: Kind of stupid distinction to give a different list with sudo and without but ok, helped me anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this issue recently, but I figured out why and solved it successfully.

At first, `sudo perf list` only gives me few lines of events.

For those who need the complete hardware events in `perf` and is not shown in `perf-list`, you need to install the latest `linux-tools`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-4.15.0-106-generic linux-cloud-tools-4.15.0-106-generic linux-tools-generic linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

Then, running

```
sudo perf list > perflist.txt
```

gets me 1980 lines in `perflist.txt`.